# VBA detect window font size

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data load program which helps users to upload huge amount of data data to Oracle. But each user may have their own window resolution setting and the display font size.

Is there any code that can retrieve user's window font size? Either smaller 100%, or medium 125%?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to detect the font size in the user's active Oracle application window?  Or are you referring to the Windows Display setting (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LlGG.png)?)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes, i'm referring to window display setting as this will impact the mouse coordinates i used for data loader.

Comment: wouldn't screen resolution be more applicable, to account for users with different monitor resolution?

Answer (score 3):

You can get (or set) the Windows Desktop **"zoom level"** with the associated registry key:

> ### `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels`
>
> ```
> Values: 
> 96 — Smaller 100%  
> 120 — Medium 125%  
> 144 — Larger 150%  
> 192 — XLarge 200%  
> 240 — Custom 250%  
> 288 — Custom 300%  
> 384 — Custom 400%  
> 480 — Custom 500%
> ```

---

If your goal is to determine *where to place something* relative to the screen width & height, you might be better to just check actual screen resolution with something like:

```
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" _
    Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Sub ScreenRes()
  Dim w As Long, h As Long
      w = GetSystemMetrics32(0) ' width in points
      h = GetSystemMetrics32(1) ' height in points
  MsgBox "X=" & w & ", Y=" & h
End Sub
```

Comment: Helpful zoom level hint to registry! - Allow me a hint: Sure you know, maybe not all SO contributors: so I suggest to prefix `Function` with the `PtrSafe` keyword being the recommended syntax since Office vers. 2010+ (keyword `VBA7`) which in this case is sufficient as there are no `LongPtr` types for pointers to a → handle or → memory location - c.f. [Declare statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/declare-statement) @ashleedawg